# Slickgrid autoEdit specific columns

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

How can I set a specific SlickGrid column to autoEdit?

`autoEdit` is a property of the grid, but it applies to all columns. I need to set only the first column to autoEdit. I suspect I can subscribe to the `onActiveCellChanged` event, but need help with how to instruct SlickGrid to go into edit mode.